Is life common in the Original Macross universe?
If we limit ourselves to the original Japanese language Macross continuity - the TV show and everything that's canon to it - and exclude reimagining, non-canonical spinoff animation, comics, radio plays and novels, and unrelated franchises that were part of the Robotech continuity but not Macross, is the existence of life beyond Earth considered common or rare, or is it simply impossible to know given the limited amount of information?
Is this something that's spoken off by characters, or commented on in any way in universe?
I'm deliberately limiting this question to the original Macross, as there are just too many other versions out there and some limits are needed.

It depends on what you mean by common and what you consider life. Do you only consider sentient life? Do the AI sentience (I.e., a certain virturoid) from Macross Plus count as life? Are we only considering the known in-universe Milky Way galaxy? Each of the main series focuses on different alien species that ultimately befriends mankind.
Many of the sentient races featured in the Macross are humanoids were, for a lack of a better word, created by Protoculture. They can vary greatly from from being genetically enginneered to naturally evolved (with the help of some genetic influencing) species. There are notably two exceptions which are hive minded sentinel microorganisms know as the Vajra and the (partially corporeal, pressing the Evil series) multidimensional energy beings known as the the Protodevlin. Life within the Macross universe is quite varied beside the well-known Zentraedi, there are marsupial Zola species, the Vordor catfolk, the Ragna merfolk, and the Windemerians. Humanoid life is pretty common and generally the norm in the galaxy of Macross series thanks to Protoculture. Aside from those Protoculture seeded species, there's also the Space Whales from Macross 7 Dynamite, which shows there's other life beyond the Protoculture.
The fact that theses forms of life in addition to the Protoculture, it's Stellar Republic and it's seeded colonies, and military forces that oppose it exist shows that there is a lot more to the universe to be explored. How common or uncommon they are remains to be explored.

Side note: While just a theory, disputed by fans, in terms of canon, neither the original SDF Macross nor DYRL are really canon per say. The real canonical history is the original planned 48-episode series that was never made due to a sponsor dropping out at the last minute. According to Shoji Kawamori a Macross production is just one interpretation of how things happened, so SDF Macross is one interpretation of Space War I from one perspective, while DYRL is is another interpretation of Space War I, with the real Space War I being some combination of both.

Ancient AI form Macross Plus? I don't remember that bit.

It's implied that the biochip installed in Sharon Apple may have been of extraterrestrial origin, possibly derived from some sort of ancient AI (like fold quartz from the Protoculture, specifically the Bird Human), but it's just an unconfirmed theory. Tangentially related from the Zettai Live movie for Delta it's specified that Yami_Q_Ray is essentially Sharon Apple (according to the promo material). Using DNA from a certain ancient being in place of the "faulty" biochip.

I have the full set on DVD in the original Japanese. Could you please narrow that down to a specific scene. Macross Plus exists isn't canonical to any other part of the franchise, it's standalone.

I don't know which set from which publisher you're referring to, are you referring to the Animego DVDs of SDF Macross? There's a lot of bootlegs out there so there's no actual complete collection of the entire franchise. Macross Plus is it's own standalone OVA and movie set, not part of the SDF. Macross Plus is canon to the main universe chronology. It happens in 2040 of the Macross timeline. If you have a question about canonicity please ask it in a separate question

The scene where the chip is installed is after the Atlantis Dome concert where Yang hack into Sharon’s system with a wrist computer during the "Idol Talk" song. Around the 16 minute mark of the 2nd OVA episode, about 28 minutes into the movie version.

I have the original Japanese language edition, nothing is mentioned about it being based on ancient technology.

it's not a box set. I have the individual Japanese DVD. I brought them monthly at the time of release.

I did say it was an unconfirmed theory.

All the Macross stories happen between 1999 and 2067. Considering in 68 years they came across with at least 4 different alien species (the ones I remember now), and the galaxy / our universe is incredibly huge , and crossing them by chance is extremely unlikely, I'd say life in the Macross universe is common
